# One samba directory is very slow

Tags: samba

We have a RHEL server running as a Samba server for our Windows network which has been running fine for ages. All of a sudden this morning one specific folder became really slow and sometimes inaccessible. It's the `/home/` directory (containing all of the user specific stuff, like their windows desktops, documents etc). It's not only really slow over the network, but when I try to use ls to view the directory it just hangs.

I'm getting loads of messages like the following in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Mar 20 09:53:32 zeus smbd[32378]: [2012/03/20 09:53:32, 0] smbd/service.c:set_current_service(184) 
Mar 20 09:53:32 zeus smbd[32378]:   chdir (/opt/shares/home/tim.rosser) failed
```

What could be causing this slowness with Samba?

Comment: Not sure what was causing it, but a restart (last resort I know, but another guy did it) has fixed it, at least for now. Accessing the directory both locally and over the network is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Check the filesystem on the disk with `fsck` and the disk itself with  `smartctl`, this might be a corrupted file system.